# how to deal with resources for celery docker

Tags: python, celery

I am building python web app using `dash` and for long running tasks, I am using `celery`.The application is dockerized with following services:

```
docker-compose.yaml

db: # postgres image
redis: # redis image
flower: # flower image
web: # dash app
celery: # clone of web
```

The app starts successfully and all services are up and running. Initially I started with tasks that take few minutes to complete.

**Observation for small tasks**

- The tasks are getting completed with returning the result.(if not terminated)
- If task is terminated using `SIGUSR1`, it is terminated successfully. `result.revoke(terminate=True, signal=SIGUSR1)`

After this small win,I began with tasks that takes hours to complete.

I opened another terminal to monitor `CPU` and `Memory` for `celery` using `top` command and lauched the app in another terminal.

**Observation for long tasks** (repeated 4-5 times and getting this pattern)

**Case-1: Terminating a long running task**

- The task is started.

```
1. CPU(switches between 100.0 and 99.0) and Memory(was at 4 and keeps on increasing)
2. After some time about `45mins`, The CPU(drastically switches to 50, then 23) and Memory(same maintained rather high 80)
3. After that, I terminated the task and it was successfully revoked(can be seen in flower)
4. But the terminal on which I was running top, CPU and Memory (values Keep on decreasing very slowly) and other column Time(keeps on increasing)
```

So for `point-4`, even the task is aborted, the resources are still showing in terminal for `celery` service and column `Time` (which still keeps on increasing) making me to think

1. Whether the task is still running?
2. Does anything specifically needed to handle `celery` service resources for docker?